# Mocking of non-copyable objects

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, mocking, smart-pointer

I find myself often in the situation where I want to mock a non-copyable object, for example a `DbHandle` handle.
I was going back and forth looking at different design choices, and I settled on the following design:

In my production code, there is no need for a client of the `Repository` to know the `DbHandle` object, but for the unit tests, this `DbHandle` object is exactly the one I want to mock.
I settled for `unique_ptr` because they make clear that the `Respository` owns the `DbHandle`, even if it is created outside.

```
#include <memory>

class Repository {
public:
    Repository() : d_dbHandel(std::unique_ptr<DbHandel>(new DbHandle("default"))) {
        d_dbHandel->open("myDB");
    }

    Repository(std::unique_ptr<DbHandle> DbHandle) :
        d_dbHandel(std::move(DbHandle) {
    }

    inline DbHandle& getDbHandel() {
        return *d_dbHandel;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<DbHandel> d_dbHandel;
};
```

What are some of the flaws of this approach?

Comment: I'm not sure what it is that you're trying to accomplish here.  All I see is a lot of boilerplate for a `DBHandle` object (but no other functionality), which by your own admission is not even needed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What I try to accomplish is to be able to injest a mocked DBHandle object in the scenario where DBHandle is non-copiable.

Comment: Yes, but what is the purpose of that?  What will it accomplish?

Comment: @Robert Harvey Mocking, for example a database connection, allows you to unit test the behavior of the class owning the db connection without actually having to establish any connection. While in production the db connection is entirely hidden inside the Repository during testing, one has to have the chance to set it. I want to achieve this without compromising my business logic (too much).

Comment: Usually, what you are mocking is already exposed as a touch point for the actual class you are testing.  It is unusual to expose a touch point for testing that won't actually be used in production.  That would mean you are testing code that isn't in the production system.

Comment: I'm not well versed in using Mocks, however in general if you want to make a object non-copyable then simply delete the copy constructors or make them private.

Answer (score 1):

What you do is mostly correct.

You can ask yourself if you are not exposing your code simply because of testing. This is indeed a shortcoming. The client does not need to know about the `DbHandle`, but the `Repository` does not either! Strictly speaking, how can you unit-test the repository if it depends on (knows) a concrete implementation `DbHandle`?

Therefore the solution is to always inject `DbHandle`, either from the unit test or from a wrapper class or factory function and to use an abstract class `DbHandle`. Create a derived concrete class `DbDefault` that is normally used.

Also I do not recommend exposing members via getters as in your getDbHandel() function.

This could be an improved design:

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<Repository> createRepository()
{
    return std::make_unique<Repository>( std::make_unique<DbDefault>() );
} 

class Repository {
public:
    explicit Repository(std::unique_ptr<DbHandle> dbHandle) :
        d_dbHandel(std::move(dbHandle) {
}

void storeValue(double x) {
    d_dbHandel->storeValue(x);
}

private:
    std::unique_ptr<DbHandel> d_dbHandel;
};
```